# Find a string and replace another string after the first is found

Tags: sed

File:

```
1
2
3
4
1
5
6
7
4
```

I would like to search for a string, in this case `1`, and then change the next string of `4` to `8`.
Expected output:

```
1
2
3
8
1
5
6
7
4
```

I've tried:

```
cat file | sed '/1/ s/4/8/'
```

But that only looks for a string to change in that line.
I also can't use line number to replace in my original file because there might be a different number of lines between the first string and the second.
I do not have GNU sed installed.

Comment: if the first occurence of 4 has to be changed you don't need anything `sed "/4/8/" file ` that's all    /foo/ s/bar/foo/ means on line with foo .... substitute....

Comment: What if there's another `1` further down which is followed by another `4` ? Do you need to replace only the 1st `4` in the file which occurs after a `1` or do you need to repeat that for each 1st `4` that follows after a `1` ?

Comment: Yes I edited the file and expected output. Sorry

Comment: @user1712037,how about `awk` solution?

Comment: Sure. What would the awk syntax look like?

Comment: The question itself helped me understand how to edit a string right after the first occurrence of a given sub-string!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [POSIX-specified file editor, `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html), is capable of doing exactly that.

```
printf '%s\n' '/1//4/s//8/' x | ex file.txt
```

`ex` is capable of combining multiple addresses.  So `/1/` means "Go to" (or refer to) "the next line matching regex `1`."  Then `/4/` goes *from that line* to the next line matching `4`.  And `s//8/` has the usual meaning; as in Sed, a blank regex passed to the `s` command means "reuse last regex used" which in this case is `4`.

To print the modified file but not save the changes, use the following command instead:

```
printf '%s\n' '/1//4/s//8/' %p | ex file.txt
```

Just to give the idea of multiple addresses better, the following command deletes the first line containing `cherry` *before* the first line containing `banana` *after* line 27:

```
printf '%s\n' '27/banana/?cherry?d' x | ex file.txt
```

`x` means to save changes and exit, and `%p` means "print whole file."  (`%` is a synonym for `1,$`, which is an address range from the first line to the last line.)

Answer (score 1):

To replace only the 1st `PATTERN` that occurs after a `MARKER` you could do:

```
sed '/MARKER/,${
/PATTERN/{
x
//{
x
b
}
g
s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/
}
}' infile
```

Use a range (from the 1st `MARKER` to the end of file) and the hold buffer. Each time you encounter a line matching `PATTERN`  you exchange buffers and check if the line that was in hold space matches too: if it does, then exchange back and go to end of script; else overwrite with current line and replace.

Answer (score 1):

generic solution using `awk`, consider the following modified input file with multiple `1`s and `4`s

```
$ cat ip.txt
1
foo
1
xyz
4
4
1
1
eeeee
4
1
rrrrrr
4
1
4
```

Use a flag to indicate that `1` was matched and a counter to know which block is being modified. Clearing the flag is needed to start the matching cycle again

```
$ # first block
$ awk '/1/{f=1} f && /4/{c++; f=0; if(c==1) $0="8"} 1' ip.txt
1
foo
1
xyz
8
4
1
1
eeeee
4
1
rrrrrr
4
1
4

$ # second block
$ awk '/1/{f=1} f && /4/{c++; f=0; if(c==2) $0="8"} 1' ip.txt
1
foo
1
xyz
4
4
1
1
eeeee
8
1
rrrrrr
4
1
4
```

can be simplified for changing only first block

```
awk '/1/{f=1} f && !c && /4/{c++; $0="8"} 1' ip.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '$1==1{ f++ }f==1 && $1==4{ $1=8 }1' file
```

The output:

```
1
2
3
8
1
5
6
7
4
```

Comment: awk '$1==1{ f++ }f==1 && $1==4{ $1=8 }1' num.txt
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @user1712037, it can not be so. Check if you run this command as standalone, not as part of some pipeline or else. Or ... you are not on Linux system

Comment: This won't work if there are multiple lines matching `1` before the 1st `4` that follows...

Comment: @don_crissti, I don't see such input sample - share some link to the text fragment you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

With awk it is more easy and compatible to any Nth occurrence needed

```
awk '/pattern to search/{n+=1}{if (n==OCCURRENCE){sub("PATTERN","SUBSTITUTE",$0)};print }' FILE-NAME
```

example :

```
-bash-4.4$ cat toto
1
2
3
4
5
6
1
2
3
4
5
6
1
2
3
4
-bash-4.4$ awk '/4/{n+=1}{if (n==2){sub("4","---8",$0)};print }' toto
1
2
3
4
5
6
1
2
3
---8
5
6
1
2
3
4
-bash-4.4$
```

only the second 4 is changed but not the first or the last.

Comment: but this is not even checking if `1` occurred first...