# Find a string and replace another string on a following line after the first string is found

Tags: awk, yaml, ex

Given a file with the following content:

```
pkg1:
  replicaCount: 1
  image:
    tag: latest
    pullPolicy: Always

pkg2:
  replicaCount: 2
  image:
    tag: latest
    pullPolicy: Always
```

I want to search for the `tag` that is attached to a specific package (ie. `pkg1`) and replace `latest` with something else (ie. `junk`) so that I get:

```
pkg1:
  replicaCount: 1
  image:
    tag: junk
    pullPolicy: Always

pkg2:
  replicaCount: 2
  image:
    tag: latest
    pullPolicy: Always
```

Thanks to the accepted answer for this post ([Find a string and replace another string after the first is found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418946/find-a-string-and-replace-another-string-after-the-first-is-found)) I can do it using 'ex':

```
printf "%s\n" "/pkg1//latest/s//junk/" x | ex info.txt;
```

but the problem is that this is running in an image which doesn't have 'ex'.

Is there a way to do with with 'awk'?  I suppose I can read in the file line by line and do something that way, but I was looking for something simpler.  If it were single line, it wouldn't be an issue.  And I can't always assume it's the first occurrence or the second occurrence.  Hence I have to search for the package name and only replace the tag for that package.

Comment: Is this an YAML file? Recommend using syntax aware parsers for modifying their content

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use a command line YAML parser:

```
$ yq -y '.pkg1.image.tag |= "junk"' file
pkg1:
  replicaCount: 1
  image:
    tag: junk
    pullPolicy: Always
pkg2:
  replicaCount: 2
  image:
    tag: latest
    pullPolicy: Always
```

I'm using `yq`, [Andrey Kislyuk's `jq` wrapper for YAML documents](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (there are other tools called `yq` too, make sure you use the correct one).

The command sets the `.pkg1.image.tag` key's value to the string `junk`, and the `-y` option is used to generate YAML output (as opposed to the default which is JSON).

With the `yq` that I believe is the default on Debian-based Linux distributions, you  will have to convert the YAML document to JSON, do the modification with `jq`, and the convert it back:

```
$ yq r -j file.yml | jq '.pkg1.image.tag |= "junk"' | yq r -P -
pkg1:
  replicaCount: 1
  image:
    tag: junk
    pullPolicy: Always
pkg2:
  replicaCount: 2
  image:
    tag: latest
    pullPolicy: Always
```

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` is available:

```
PKG=pkg1 FIELD=tag VALUE=junk perl -pi -e '
  $pkg = $1 if /^(\S.*?)\s*:\s*$/;
  s/^\s+\Q$ENV{FIELD}\E\s*:\s*\K.*/$ENV{VALUE}/ if $pkg eq $ENV{PKG}' -- "$file"
```

Except with the recent versions of the GNU implementation, `awk` doesn't support editing files in-place¹. If your `awk` is actually a recent gawk, you could do the equivalent of the above with:

```
PKG=pkg1 FIELD=tag VALUE=junk gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk -e '
  match($0, /^([^[:space:]](.*[^[:space:]])?)[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*$/, f) {
   pkg = f[1] ""
 }
 pkg == ENVIRON["PKG"] {
   $0 = gensub("^([[:space:]]+"ENVIRON["FIELD"]"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*).*", \
               "\\1" ENVIRON["VALUE"], 1)
 }
 {print}' -E /dev/null "$file"
```

I have tried to work around a few of the limitations and `awk`wardnesses of the `awk` API:

- parameters passed as env vars as using the `-v var=value` method mangles backslashes
- `pkg = f[i] ""`: append a `""` to make sure `pkg` is considered as string to ensure the comparison is always a string comparison (`awk` doesn't have the `==` vs `eq` of `perl`)
- `-e 'code' -E /dev/null "$file"` (a GNU extension) is required for it to work with arbitrary file names.

but there are still a few left, which means it could still not work properly in some corner cases with some input:

- There's no equivalent of `perl`'s `\Q`/`\E`, so it won't work properly if the `FIELD` contains awk regexp operators (`.^${}[]\?+*|` characters)
- it won't work properly if `VALUE` contains `&` or `\` characters as those are treated specially in `gawk`'s `gensub()` replacement argument.

---

<sup>¹ **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`</sup>